# Wifi automatic off after time

Tags: networking, 20.04, wireless, suspend

I'm using 20.04.
If I leave my laptop a while, maybe 5 minutes, **Wifi auto off**. Sometime it happens when I'm using.The laptop cann't find any wifi. I cann't find out any solution. I usualy **Suspend** then turn on again to Wifi work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89Ikw.png)

That is an decription image.

And this is *log* when I run `sudo service NetworkManager status`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqjeG.png)

Hope its usefull.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your wireless may be dropping because of power management; that is, the feature where the card partially powers down to save battery power during periods of inactivity and then, ideally, powers back up seamlessly when activity resumes. Let's disable power saving to see if it helps. From the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
```

Restart Network Manager:

```
sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

Is there any improvement?

Comment: it does not work for me